# 127.0.0.1 is working but localhost is not working

Tags: php, apache

I am using apache and php.I installed apache and can do operations like stop,start,restart successfully.But my localhost is not working and surprisingly 127.0.0.1 is working fine.

When i type 127.0.0.1 my browser is showing "**It Works**".But when i type localhost my browser is showing "**Web page is not available**".

> To solve this I tried the following
>
> 1. thought it might be hosts file problem and opened my hosts file in C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt and wrote "127.0.0.1
>      localhost" at the end of the file
> 2. thought it might be httpd.conf file problem and opened m httpd.conf file in apache/conf and uncommented "ServerName
>      localhost:80"
> 3. thought it might be port problem and uninstalled skype

though the problem persists.

How to solve this?

Comment: As for the off-topic flagging; whichever software OP is using (WAMP/ LAMP/ XAMPP/ ...), a local server is involved and therefore it's a tool *primarily used for programming*.. Flags on subjective/ edge-cases are really frustrating, as is the need to register to every StackExchange for closely related questions. On topic: [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/321329/wamp-server-wont-work) might be of help.

Answer (score 2):

In httpd.conf, change `ServerName localhost:80` to `ServerName *:80`

Comment: but OP says localhost isnt working, 127.0.01 is working. not vice verse

Comment: A.B. Exactly. That's what this answer should fix.

Comment: ohkay great.. @Ed  Cotrrell

Comment: no,it is not working

Comment: Do you have the right directory set for the files you are trying to serve?